# React Native - Deeplink doesn't works on android's release build

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, deep-linking

I have issues with react-native deeplinks on android.
Deep link works when in debug mode but when i generate release build, it doesn't works.

It opens app though but doesn't route to expected path.
url is null

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(Platform.OS === 'android'){
        Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
            this.navigate(url);
        });
    }else {
        Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
    }
}

componentWillUnmount() { 
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
  }

  handleOpenURL = (event) => { 
    this.navigate(event.url);
  }

navigate = (url) => { 
    const route = url.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, '');
    const routeName = route.split('/')[1];
    const uri = new URL(url)

    if (routeName === 'invitation') {
      this.props.router.go('IntroScreen');
    };
  }
```

Comment: any solution for this